# Add CSS to an iframe inside an iframe wihout ID using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have this iframe inside an iframe. Both of this iframe has no ID. The code looks like this:

```html
<div id="Test">
  <iframe>
    <iframe>
      <head>
        <style>*CSS code right here*</style>
      </head>
      <body>
      </body>
    </iframe>
  </iframe>
</div>
```

Could i add some CSS on the 2nd iframe using javascript?

Comment: Do you have access to the pages inside any of the iFrames?

Comment: I only have access on the first iframe

Comment: You need access to any page inside an iframe to be able to affect it.

Comment: Actually, the 2nd iframe is autogenerate by the system for ads banner. I think, if i could trick the 2nd iframe display css, i could make it disappear.

Answer (score -1):

To fetch the next iframe try this..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("iframe").next(iframe).css({"color": "red"});});
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It seems like has no effect at all.

Comment: then I think accessing iframe in iframe is difficult... but to get next element by jquery the above code give you the answer I think...

Comment: Thank you very much for your help..:)